# How to access phpmyadmin in cloud

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, xampp, bitnami

I have deployed my xampp server to the Google cloud using [bitnami tutorial](https://www.apachefriends.org/docs/hosting-xampp-on-google.html). The next day when I try to access

> 127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin/

I can't seem to. I initiated ssh using puTTy and I have the welcome page like so. I am getting the "Unable to connect" generic response from firefox. And I am getting "the remote device or resource cannot accept connection" in IE. Is there any way to debug this?

[image]

Update: I added the my.cnf file in mysql folder in the cloud. Are the configurations right?

[image]

This is my log file image.

[image]

Here serverip/xampp/ shows that mysql is deactivated

[image]

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here. Did you configure the tunnels section of putty? It seems that you're not properly forwarding the port. Apart from that, please note that you need to use **127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin** instead of **127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin**. I hope it helps.

Comment: @JotaMartos I did use 127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin. I also configured PuTTy tunnels. Is there anyway I can debug it from my local environment?

Comment: What does the port 8888 refer to? Is the localhost:80 in my local environment? How do those two in the tunnels section work together?

Comment: Could you please share with us the session log of putty? You'll find how to save the log in the "Logging" section of the application.

Comment: @JotaMartos, I did add my log from PuTTy.